# wp_localize_script not working on ajax response

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

When a file is uploaded to my page I make an ajax call to add an entry in a database. I then want to send a string back to the client using wp_localize_script but when I try to access it I just get an error saying "Uncaught Reference Error: pw_script_vars is not defined".

I know I can send something back with wp_die but this is a bit of a work around that I don't think is the correct way. So the question is why is the wp_localize_script not working? Any help appreciated.

script.js:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
jQuery(function($) {
    var i;
    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
            $('body').on('change', '#file'+i, function() {
                var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                var form_data = new FormData();

                form_data.append('file', file_data);
                form_data.append('action', 'file_upload');

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert( pw_script_vars.alert );
                    }

                });

            });
    }
});
```

functions.php:

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','owr_scripts_function');
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_file_upload', 'file_upload_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_file_upload', 'file_upload_callback' );

    function owr_scripts_function() {
          wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), time(), false);
    }
function file_upload_callback(){
    wp_localize_script('script', 'pw_script_vars', array(
            'alert' => __('Hey! You have clicked the button!', 'pippin'),
            'message' => __('You have clicked the other button. Good job!', 'pippin')
        )
    );
    wp_die("upload success");
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code :

script.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var i;
    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
        $('body').on('change', '#file'+i, function() {
            var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var form_data = new FormData();

            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            form_data.append('action', 'file_upload');

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: pw_script_vars.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert( response.alert );
                }

            });

        });
    }
});
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','owr_scripts_function', 20);
function owr_scripts_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), time(), false);
    wp_localize_script(
        'script', 
        'pw_script_vars', 
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        )
    );
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_file_upload', 'file_upload_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_file_upload', 'file_upload_callback' );
function file_upload_callback(){
    $response = [];
    $response['alert'] = __('Hey! You have clicked the button!', 'pippin');
    $response['message'] = __('You have clicked the other button. Good job!', 'pippin');
    wp_send_json($response);
    wp_die("upload success");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and although this does work I need to run the wp_localize_script from the file_upload_callback method. Is there a way to do this? (reason is that I've put a trivial string into wp_localize_script for sake of example but I'm actually sending something that I pull from the database dynamically)

Comment: @dreddx Please try above edited code.You doesn't need to add response into wp_localize_script.Directly you can send into ajax function.

Comment: Great, thank you